# Delphi XE2 Code Completion Broken

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, code-completion

The code completion is broken on my fresh install of Delphi XE2.  It was working previously, but then stopped out of the blue.  I completely uninstalled (removed registry settings too), reinstalled, and now it doesn't work even for a brand new application.

Also of note the error insight is complaining about everything.

Is there a path issue somewhere?

Should the Project `Options --> Delphi Compiler --> Unit Aliases` have a default value? (Mine is blank)

Comment: Do you have update 4? Do you have IDE Fix Pack?

Comment: Unit aliases are not relevant. Read the documentation to learn why not.

Comment: I do not have the IDE Fix Pack.  I will check that out again, but I did have the previously installed when it was broken.

Comment: After installing the IDE Fix pack again it seeminngly works now.

Comment: I've had this. I find that it comes and goes too. Moving to XE3 seemed to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's old question, but I discovered that if line-endings were mixed (some lines LF, others CR and even CRLF) this can happen. Use dos2unix in a batch or Notepad++ (if single/few files) to fix that.